# Sample a few lines from an strace printout

Tags: text-processing, strace

I've got a process that I want to inspect with strace, but since it's printing out a lot of stuff, I would like to sample only a few lines every X seconds from it. Is there any way of doing that with bash or similar?

For example:

```
strace -p 123456 | "print out most recent 80 lines every 2 seconds"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
strace -p $PID >$PID.log &
watch tail -n80 $PID.log >$PID-sample.log &
tail -f $PID-sample.log
```

or just `watch tail -n$LINES $PID.log` if you don't need to scroll back through the sampled log.